# Microsoft Visual Studio doesn't change Version Number on building

Tags: c#, visual-studio, version

as i wrote in the title i've got the Problem that I'm not able to change the Version number of my Project.
I've already gone trough multiple Threads of people with particular problems, but all they've suggested was to change the AssemblyInfo to this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

to increment the Version automatically with the Microsoft Algorithm ([DaysSince2000].[SecondsSinceMidnight]) but it doesn't work.

When I build the Project, the changedate of the nugetpackage changes, but the versionnumber doesn't. Even if I change the versionnumber hard (e.g. to 1.0.4711.1337 or something like that) the versionnumber of the file doesn't change. Is there a Timeinterval defined for when the versionnumber changes?

Thank you for your answers :)